# Custom fields in a meteor route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have my a number of routes inside my routes.js file and i want to introduce an extra field into it. Below is the route

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  controller: 'LoginController',
  where: 'client',
  action:'index'
});
```

Since i have a number of routes,i want to go through all the routes and get the route name like this

```
_.each(Router.routes, function(route){
  console.log(route.getName());
});
```

I want to use the route names to generate links. Links require link names and i have the idea of putting the link names in the routes.

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  controller: 'LoginController',
  where: 'client',
  text: 'Login Link',
  action:'index'
});
```

Is introducing custom fields in the routes allowed in meteor?.

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is a `title` option but its not in the docs http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-specific-options

and used it this way

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'login',
  controller:'HomeController',
  where: 'client',
  title: 'login', 
  icon: 'this is the icon',
  action:'index'
});
```

and to get the options

```
Router.routes.forEach(function(route){
  console.log(route.getName());
  console.log(route.options.title);
  console.log(route.options.icon);
});
```

and this is the result

```
login
login
this is the icon
```

so even the custom option `icon` seems to be working.